# Scheduled Task not working in multi-server environment

Tags: scheduled-tasks

I have created a scheduled task in Sitecore, which runs fine in our Staging environment but the task did not trigger when moved to Production.

There are no related logs or errors. The last run time is also not updated.

I read that, tasks will not be triggered when app pool is down. But the site is up and working fine.

When I try to browse the "keep-alive" page in prod, nothing happens and same case with any admin page. Seems, they were disabled.

Could it be a reason, that keep-alive is down and task is not triggered?

We have one CM & one CD server for prod. The instance is in CM. I have updated Sitecore.config in both CM & CD like this:

```
<agent type="Sitecore.Tasks.TaskDatabaseAgent" method="Run" interval="00:10:00" />

<agent name="Web_Database_Agent" type="Sitecore.Tasks.DatabaseAgent" method="Run" interval="00:15:00">
        <param desc="database">web</param>
        <param desc="schedule root">/sitecore/system/tasks/schedules</param>
        <LogActivity>true</LogActivity>
    </agent>
```

Comment: If task is defined in web database and both task command and scheduled are published, you cannot choose on which of the servers (CM or CD) it will be executed. Are you sure that this task should be executed in web database context? Can you tell bit more what is the responsibility of this task?